# React Testing Library. Test length of string in textfield

Tags: reactjs, testing, material-ui, react-testing-library

I am testing disabling a button if the length in an input field is >= 100 chars.
RTL is being buggy in that doing something like this doesn't always work:

```
      userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/Name/i), 'n'.repeat(101))

      expect(await screen.findByLabelText(/Name/i)).toHaveValue(
        'n'.repeat(101),
      )
```

The above sometimes fails with the error that the string is expected to have 101 chars but RTL only enters 100 into the field, below is the error log from a failure.

```
Step #1 - "test":     expect(element).toHaveValue(nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn)
Step #1 - "test": 
Step #1 - "test":     Expected the element to have value:
Step #1 - "test":       nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
Step #1 - "test":     Received:
Step #1 - "test":       nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
```

I believe a more robust test would be to test that the length of the input field value is greater than a certain length.
However, having some trouble trying to fetch the value of the input so I can test its length. Below is the code, note I am using MUI TextField for the input elements.

```
    it('disables save button on newly created step in edit state when input field has more than 100 characters', async () => {
      render(<Component />)
      await waitFor(
        () => {
          expect(screen.getByText('Add')).toBeInTheDocument()
          userEvent.click(screen.getByText('Add'))
        },
        { timeout: 10000 },
      )

      userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/Name/i), 'n'.repeat(101))

      expect(await screen.findByLabelText(/Name/i)).toHaveValue(
        'n'.repeat(101),
      )
      expect(await screen.findByText('Save')).toBeDisabled()
    })
```

How can I go about testing that the field's value.length is >=100 instead of using toHaveValue().

Comment: Have you tried `expect(screen.getByLabelText(/Name/i).value).toHaveLength(101)`?